# Memory error NZEC when using C# on HackerEarth

Tags: c#

I am solving a [question on HackerEarth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/friends-relationship-1/). The test case passes successfully, but the rest of the cases show a NZEC error. I know NZEC stands for Non Zero Exit Code but I am not sure why this is happening here.

Any insight about why this happens and how I can optimize my code (preferably without changing the logic) will help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int t = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr = new int[3];
        for(int m = 0; m < t; m++)
        {
            arr[m] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        for (int n = 0; n < t; n++)
        {
            int i, j;
            for (i = 0; i < arr[n]; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 2 * arr[n]; j++)
                {
                    if (j <= i || j >= 2 * arr[n] - 1 - i)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("#");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Once you determine what `NZEC` stands for, then the resolution should become apparent.

Comment: `int[] arr = new int[3];` - what if t > 3 ?

Comment: I'd also guess your output is wrong: `Console.WriteLine("\n");` will write two line breaks not one, and I think you only need one for each of these. And possibly not a trailing line after the final pattern, but you might get away with that.

Comment: @Rup Thank you. Apparently keeping new int[3] was the problem. I was supposed to have new int[t] there.